DOMException: Failed to execute 'share' on 'Navigator': Must be handling a user gesture to perform a share request
I am trying to share an image from mobile native sharer. On click of a button, adding a div which image needs to be captured.
Here is the sequence -

user clicks the button, a new state is set
element is attached to DOM
useEffect found the dom node, it captures the image
another useEffect waiting for capturedImage to not null and then it share the image via navigator.share

On page reload, for slower network, for first time, I am always getting this error - "DOMException: Failed to execute 'share' on 'Navigator': Must be handling a user gesture to perform a share request"
But next click onwards it works fine.
const ShareButton = ({
    title, className, children
}: TShareButtonProps) => {
    const { asPath } = useRouter();
    const lbKey = asPath.split('/')[2];
    const [capturedImage, setCapturedImage] = useState([] as File[]);
    const [isSharingInProgress, setIsSharingInProgress] = useState(false);

    const handleShareButtonClick = () => {
        setIsSharingInProgress(true);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const node = document.getElementById(ELEMENT_IDS.LeaderboardTop10) as HTMLElement;
        const buildPng = async (nodeEl: HTMLElement) => {
            // calling toBlob for the nodeEl abd returing dataUrl
        };

        const getImageFile = async (nodeEl: HTMLElement) => {
            try {
                const blob = await buildPng(nodeEl);
                if (blob && blob.size) {
                    const files = [new File([blob], `image_${lbKey}.png`, { type: 'image/png' })]
                    setCapturedImage(files);
                } else {
                    setCapturedImage([new File([new Blob()], 'failed.png', { type: 'image/png' })]);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                setCapturedImage([new File([new Blob()], 'failed.png', { type: 'image/png' })]);
            }
        };

        if (node) {
            getImageFile(node);
        }

        // Cleanup function to reset capturedImage when asPath changes
        return () => {
            setCapturedImage([]);
        };
    }, [isSharingInProgress, asPath, lbKey]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const sharePost = async () => {
            if (navigator.share) {
                try {
                    await navigator.share({
                        files: capturedImage
                    });
                } catch (err: any) {
                    // user cancelling the share is not an error
                    if (err.name !== 'AbortError') {
                        toast({
                            title: 'Something went wrong!'
                        });
                    }
                } finally {
                    setIsSharingInProgress(false);
                }
            } else {
                toast({
                    title: 'sharing is not supported on device!'
                });
                setIsSharingInProgress(false);
            }
        };

        if (isSharingInProgress && capturedImage && capturedImage.length) {
            sharePost();
        }
    }, [isSharingInProgress, capturedImage]);


    const isImageCapturingInProgress = isSharingInProgress && (!capturedImage || capturedImage.length === 0);
    const isImageCapturedFailed = isSharingInProgress && (capturedImage.length && capturedImage[0].size === 0);

    return (
        <>
            <div className='flex justify-end mr-4'>
                <Button
                    disabled={!!(isImageCapturingInProgress || isImageCapturedFailed)}
                    className={cn(
                        "flex px-4 py-2 justify-center items-center bg-black rounded-lg text-white md:hidden",
                        className,
                        isImageCapturingInProgress || isImageCapturedFailed
                            ? 'bg-gray-400 cursor-not-allowed'
                            : 'bg-black text-white'
                    )}
                    onClick={handleShareButtonClick}>
                    <>
                        <span className="text-xs md:text-[14px]">
                            {title}
                        </span>
                        { isImageCapturingInProgress && !isImageCapturedFailed ? (
                            <SpinnerIcon className="w-4 h-4 animate-spin ml-1" />
                        ) : (
                            <ShareIcon className='ml-1' />
                        )}
                    </>
                </Button>
            </div>
            {
                isSharingInProgress && children
            }
        </>
    );
}

Solution tried -

Add the element in DOM already. Let the image be ready first, till then keep the share button disabled and once image is ready, enable the button and share.

This works fine but unnecessary HTML will present in DOM, also it impacts on performance as it increases total blocking time.

Try to code everything in the click handler. Still I get the same error.

What I observed is if you have any async call which takes time then navigator.share raise concern as it think it was called without any user action. But I'm wondering why it works after that as I am not caching the image.
Any possible solution?
